# D3.js tspan font size issue in edge

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am using D3 to dynamically update content in web page. I am creating and updating `tspan` element using code give below.

```
 this.dataLabel = this.contentGrp
     .append("tspan")
     .classed("dataLabel", true)
     .attr("dx", () => {
         if (this.prefixSettings.show == true && this.prefixSettings.text != null) {
             return this.prefixSettings.spacing;
         } else {
             return 0;
         }
     })
     .style({
         "text-anchor": "start",
         "font-size": this.dataLabelSettings.fontSize * fontMultiplier,
         "fill": this.conditionSettings.applyToDataLabel == true ?
             this._getCardgrpColors(conditionValue, "F", this.conditionSettings) || this.dataLabelSettings.color : this.dataLabelSettings.color,
         "font-family": this.dataLabelSettings.fontFamily,
         "font-weight": this.dataLabelSettings.isBold == true ? "bold" : "normal",
         "font-style": this.dataLabelSettings.isItalic == true ? "italic" : "normal"
     })
     .text(dataLabelType.text == true ? dataLabelValue as string : dataLabelValueFormatted as string);
```

As you can see in above code, I am assigning `font-size` through `style` function of D3. The problem is that in Edge or Internet Explorer I can not see font-size attribute applied. See screen shots below.

In chrome I can see `font-size` in debug window.

[image: chrome]

In Edge or Internet Explorer I can not see the `font-size` hence fonts are small.

[image: edge]

I am using v3.5.17 of D3. Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: Try adding "px" to the value.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for reply. I added `px` and it is working. So does chrome automatically appends pixels at the end?

Comment: Among other things...

Comment: That is neat. So how does chrome knows that it has to append `px` not other unit such as `em`?